# How to get the top of a dice in libgdx 3d?

Tags: java, math, libgdx, bullet

I have some dice rolling animation which I originally had done in javascript using THREE & CANNON and I want to reimplent it in libgdx.

The animation part is done, but I have yet to figure out how to identify the top of the dice.

I am aware of at least 3 different methods to do that, so I am unsure which of these can actually done with libgdx / bullet.

(I am struggeling with this, the other approaches sound easier)

1.
Somehow do it the mathematical way by using the rotation of the dice.

I now the oginal rotation of the dice by getting it's quaternion, 
and I can get the quaternions of the dice after it has been cast.

*I also know some of the quaternions of the rotations it should end up with (at least somewhat as the cast won't be perfect).*

---

Edit 3:
Currently I am counting 34 uniques (1: 4x, 2: 6x; 3: 5x, 4: 7x, 5: 7x, 6: 5x) out of a total of 64 possible rotations.

But there still seems to be some more ...
I calculated the 64 using the three axis and rotating each of them between 0 and 270°, in steps of 90°.

For example the following Quaternion's with a value of

```
( 0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f)  -> which should be 4
(-0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f)  -> which should be 5
```

are not covered by this approach.

Using the min distance between each coordinate seems to work better now.

---

**The mathematical way is (mostly) working, I'd still like somme feedback if the other two options can be realised within libgdx.**

The other options:

---

2.
Use raycasting to get the top of the dice.

In javasript the raycasting method delivered the mesh objects to me which were intersected and they had a property which let me identify which side it was. I haven't seen anything similiar in libgdx yet.

```
function identifyDiceTop(position) {

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

    var vec = new THREE.Vector3(position.x, position.y, 5); 
    raycaster.set( vec, new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1));

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );

    if (intersects.length > 0 && intersects[ 0 ].face != null) {
        switch (intersects[ 0 ].face.materialIndex) {
           // see which value is top
        }
    }
```

---

3.
Get the top side of the dice by finding the highest y-coordinate of a mesh of the dice object. Even simpler than above, but again can I even access the meshes somehow?

I am using the follwoing code to create the dice. But here I do not use any meshes directly, so I might need a different construction method?

```java
        MeshPartBuilder meshPartBuilder =
            modelBuilder.part(
                "box", 
                GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, 
                attr,
                new Material(
                    TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(
                        region
                    )
                )
            );

        meshPartBuilder.setUVRange(dice.side5);
        meshPartBuilder.rect(-size,-size,-size,-size,size,-size,size,size,-size,size,-size,-size,0,0,-1);
        meshPartBuilder.setUVRange(dice.side2);
        meshPartBuilder.rect(-size,size,size, -size,-size,size,size,-size,size,size,size,size,0,0,1);
        meshPartBuilder.setUVRange(dice.side6);
        meshPartBuilder.rect(-size,-size,size, -size,-size,-size,size,-size,-size,size,-size,size,0,-1,0);
        meshPartBuilder.setUVRange(dice.side1);
        meshPartBuilder.rect(-size,size,-size, -size,size,size,size,size,size,size,size,-size,0,1,0);
        meshPartBuilder.setUVRange(dice.side4);
        meshPartBuilder.rect(-size,-size,size, -size,size,size,-size,size,-size,-size,-size,-size,-1,0,0);
        meshPartBuilder.setUVRange(dice.side3);
        meshPartBuilder.rect(size,-size,-size, size,size,-size,size,size,size,size,-size,size,1,0,0);
```

I hope somebody can give me a pointer.